# java proxy seems to be failing silently. How do I make it fail loudly?

Tags: java, maven, proxy

I wrote a maven plugin that performs network activity. When I run it, I'm passing in parameters to signal it should use a proxy.

```
mvn myplugin:goal -Dhttps.proxyHost=nonexistent-site.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8000
```

Even when I point it at a nonexistent proxy, it succeeds. It seems to be bypassing the proxy and just making the network call directly if the proxy is bad. (this is my theory anyways. it could be that I'm not even setting the proxy correctly)

I've also edited the maven settings.xml and added the bad proxy host under  but it also fails silently.

Same if I add the parameters to MAVEN_OPTS

How can I make the network call fail if the proxy is bad?

Comment: Hmm I just tested with the `maven-dependency-plugin` the command `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact="log4j:log4j:1.1.3" -Dhttps.proxyHost=nonexistent-site.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8000` and it did fail. Are you sure you're using those proxy settings in your Maven plugin? Could you post its code?

Comment: I just realized I may not be. I'm using the com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest library for my network calls and perhaps they don't respect the system proxy settings since it looks like there's an API to set a Proxy object...

Comment: Looks like it doesn't yes: https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/issues/65 You need to set a proxy explicitely.

Comment: That's the answer! I just verified that I needed to create a special proxy object from the system proxy settings and it worked. Thank you @Tunaki

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem, thanks to @Tunaki.

Turns out the library (com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest) I was using doesn't respect the java proxy settings. The issue is documented/linked to in @Tunaki's comments above.

The lesson here is that if you're using a network library that's not part of the jdk, make sure it respects the java settings. 
In the case of Unirest, I had to manually create the proxy like so

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(System.getProperty("https.proxyHost")
                              , new Integer(System.getProperty("https.proxyPort")));
Unirest.setProxy(proxy);
```

I'm not sure if this question or answer really helps anyone. I'll leave it here for now in case it applies. But if anyone comments that I should delete this or I get a couple of downvotes, I'll remove the question.

Comment: I also want to note that Unirest currently does not support proxy authentication so probably use another library if that is important to you https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/issues/103